# Cannot connect to remote MySQL server from Jupyter Notebook environment

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have a Python 2.7 script that connects to a remote MySQL database using `MySQLdb`. I don't have any local MySQL server on my laptop and for the purpose of this script I don't need one. I am on Windows 10.

From the terminal, the script works fine. It connects to remote DB and runs MySQL commands without any problem. But when I run the same script from within Jupyter Notebook, I get this error:

```
Error 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

Nowhere in the script I have any reference to `localhost`.

Comment: have you tried to replace "localhost" by '127.0.0.1' or '0.0.0.0' ?